# How to share code between internal and external module

Tags: typescript

I have an internal module used in browser environment, which I would like to use in node.js. Is there a way to make it use as an external module.

int.ts

```
module internal_mod {

   export class Test {
      constructor(d:any){}
   }
}

// these all will fail
//export = internal_mod.Test;
//export function newTest(d:any) {
//    return new internal_mod.Test(d)
//}
```

How can I use this file in a node project and use like

```
import t = require('../int');
var tt = new t(null) // or something similar to instantiate the class
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `export`:

```
module internal_mod {

   export class Test {
      constructor(d:any){}
   }
}
export  = internal_mod
```

Usage :

```
import t = require('../int').Test;
var tt = new t(null) // or something similar to instantiate the class
```

Comment: thanks basarat. it looks like,the module is not recognized as an internal module (through //<reference ..) then, and gives error `Cannot find name internal_mod`.  if this is not best to do this way, what is the best way to share code between frontend(js/angular) and backend (node)

Comment: hey, looking at https://github.com/basarat/demo-fullstack now.. you got it all covered :-)

Comment: I am not ready for to use require.js at client (may involve lot of changes for an existing app). so, I guess I can't follow your example :-(

Comment: Similar to window, nodejs has 'global' that you might exploit to get you where you need to be faster. Then you can explore better ways latter.